# indent long text in a div

Tags: css

I have two div's side by side. The second div has long text and thus it goes on to next line. However when it does happen I want it to be indented so as to be aligned with the top text.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xLvHq

HTML

```
<div id="mainHeading">
<div id="imgBox">
    <span>Some image with img tag</span>
</div>
<div id="dataBox">
    <span>Very Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/xLvHq/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
#dataBox {
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
float: left;
margin-left: 20px;
}

#imgBox {
display: block;
float: left;
}
```

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xLvHq/5/

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is remove -50 value in your CSS and also change display:inline to float:left in both instances